# Session database storage laravel

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have configured laravel to use database as session storage and made a table too according to their docs. My question is that when i use the session()->put() commands there is no data being saved in the database. When i run a query to check the session data there is nothing there. But when i return this session data on the browser it shows up which means that data is being stored somewhere. I checked storage/framework/sessions and nothing is being stored in files too. Clearing my misconception will be highly regarded.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your **.env** file to set the session driver to database?

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

Comment: Yes i did but it didn't help. Got it working by using the schema as shown in the docs not by using my own session table created earlier